# Which one is bigger? $\tan(\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2})$ or $\frac{\ln(\cos \alpha)-\ln(\cos \beta)} {\beta - \alpha}$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Hello everyone which one is bigger:

- $\tan(\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2})$,  or
- $\frac{\ln(\cos \alpha)-\ln(\cos \beta)} {\beta - \alpha}$
  for $0 < \alpha < \beta < \frac{\pi}{2}$?

I tried to use some identities like $\tan(\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}) = -\frac{\cos \alpha - \cos \beta}{\sin \alpha \mp \sin \beta}$ and it looks like $\frac{\ln(\cos \alpha)-\ln(\cos \beta)} {\beta - \alpha},$

and I tried to convert it to a function but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 4):

$$ -\log\cos\beta+\log\cos\alpha = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\tan(x)\,dx $$
hence $\frac{\log\cos\alpha-\log\cos\beta}{\beta-\alpha}$ is the average value of $\tan(x)$ over the interval $[\alpha,\beta]$.
 $\tan(x)$ is a convex function on $\left[0,\pi/2\right)$, hence by the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality)

$$ \frac{\log\cos\alpha-\log\cos\beta}{\beta-\alpha}\geq \tan\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right).$$